# Cordova windows 8 app: load external javascript (google maps)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a cordova app for iOS and now I have to build it for Windows too.
The problem i'm facing is that there is a Google Maps inside the app, but when I launch it I receive this error:

> google is undefined

And in the console i find this:

> An app can't load remote web content in the local context

It seems to me that the problem is with the external resource loading.
So, how can I solve this?
Is there a way to load external resources in windows 8 apps?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem.
I found [this solution](http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/) to load a Google-map in the app. 
The writer uses an iFrame to show the map:

*default.html*

```
...
<body>
    <iframe id="Map" src="ms-appx-web:///map.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
```

*map.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&signed_in=true">
    </script>
        ...
```

I dont need to include a map but want to use the Google places library in my existing viewmodel.

I hope the given solution fixes your problem.

Answer (score -1):

does the app works on iOS or the issue is on both the platforms.

Have you added the script for google maps such as

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
```

and allow the script url in the config file as

```
<access origin="*">
```

for all the external links

Comment: Yes, the script is included and it's also allowed in the config.xml file. And yes, the app works normally on iOS.